# Why is my font awesome icon being duplicated

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

If you run the below snipped , you can see that the 'fa-enelope'email logo is being duplicated. I have never used font awesome before and am wondering if I have done something wrong.

It all changed when I included the a tag - I wonder if that has something to do with it.

I am wondering if I should just scrap the font awesome and download some other icons to use.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFF, #bfbfbf);
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9rem;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f47a42, #f45041);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #f47a42;
}
.social-icons--camera {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #f47a42;
}
.social-icons--github {
  color: #f47a42;
}
.social-icons--email {
  color: #f47a42;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>portfolio site</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="title">Adam Millington</h1>
<div class="social-icons">
  <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  <i class="social-icons--email far fa-envelope">
  </a>
    
  </i><a href="https://unsplash.com/@adammillingtonphotography" target="_blank">  <i class="social-icons--camera fas fa-camera-retro"></i></a>

  <a href="https://github.com/malefis">  <i class="social-icons--github fab fa-github" target="_blank"></i></a>





</div>
<hr>
  
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/) before posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You closed the envelope's `<i>` after the `</a>`

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFF, #bfbfbf);
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9rem;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f47a42, #f45041);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #f47a42;
}
.social-icons--camera {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #f47a42;
}
.social-icons--github {
  color: #f47a42;
}
.social-icons--email {
  color: #f47a42;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>portfolio site</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="title">Adam Millington</h1>
<div class="social-icons">
  <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  <i class="social-icons--email far fa-envelope"></i>
  </a>
    
  <a href="https://unsplash.com/@adammillingtonphotography" target="_blank">  <i class="social-icons--camera fas fa-camera-retro"></i></a>

  <a href="https://github.com/malefis">  <i class="social-icons--github fab fa-github" target="_blank"></i></a>





</div>
<hr>
  
  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You closed your `i` tag after `a` instead of before

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFF, #bfbfbf);
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9rem;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f47a42, #f45041);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #f47a42;
}

.social-icons--camera {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #f47a42;
}

.social-icons--github {
  color: #f47a42;
}

.social-icons--email {
  color: #f47a42;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>portfolio site</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="title">Adam Millington</h1>
  <div class="social-icons">
    <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
      <i class="social-icons--email far fa-envelope"></i>
    </a>


    <a href="https://unsplash.com/@adammillingtonphotography" target="_blank">
      <i class="social-icons--camera fas fa-camera-retro"></i></a>

    <a href="https://github.com/malefis"> <i class="social-icons--github fab fa-github" target="_blank"></i></a>





  </div>
  <hr>



</body>
```